# Virgin Broadband Router Websocket Issue in the UK

Tags: http, websocket, router

Has anyone had trouble keeping a websocket open with a server using the Virgin Media broadband router in the UK.  We are seeing an issue on our device with the Virgin Mobile broadband routers latest SW update running on the Hub3 - Hub5 HW.  The websocket is scrambling messages and only updating our server every hour or so.

The problem with the scrambled messages was found to disappear after the smart channel optimization was disabled.  Although, this fixed the message, we still notice the server only updating every hour as opposed to every 3 minutes.  We don't see this problem on any other router.